# Sensitivity analysis for a packing LP

Tags: reference-request, optimization, linear-programming

I have a packing problem of the form $\max p'x$ subject to $Ax\leq b$ and $x\geq 0$.
If I perturb $b$ by $\delta$ in every component, the new restriction becomes $Ax\leq b+\delta$ and one asks if the old optimal base (or optimal vertex) is still optimal.
Do you have a reference for this? Someone must have worked it out thoroughly.

A little more detail:

The textbooks I've consulted treat only the standard form $Ax=b$, where you say $A=[A_B,A_N]$ and get nice results depending on $A_B^{-1}$.
To analyse the packing problem you could either introduce dummy variables or directly solve a similar system, except that now it depends on a more complicated matrix.
I know how to do this, I'm more interested in the interpretations and intuition that someone must have developed already (also I'd like to reference it instead of writing it myself).

Thanks!!